# Length property from Spotify Album not defined?

Tags: javascript, json, api, spotify

First, I'm sorry for my language.

I am developping an application with API Spotify's and I have an error when I  try to get length property Album's but at execution, console report that property length is undefined, the same for get(index) method.

So, I checked the contents of my request and I noted that length property is not defined in the console whereas it's enable on the [Spotify API](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/4c26b7e8e0.html)?

I want to develop an application which for an user, gives all artists from library's user, name of an album by artist and name of a single from album artist's.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please show the part of your code where the error occurs (and as much of the surrounding code as necessary to provide some context).

Comment: At the very least run `typeof` against Album and let us know the result.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this (I've just typed it out here - may contain typos!):

```
var models = getSpotifyApi(1).require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
models.Album.fromURI('spotify:album:1eNPZeO8HloxcmqEt4Avve', function(album) {
    // This callback is fired when the album has loaded.
    // The album object has a tracks property, which is a standard array.
    console.log(album.tracks);
});
```

Once you have the correct album object, you can use it as documented: http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/4c26b7e8e0.html

Please note that anything from the `sp.core` namespace is unsupported. Please use the documented API instead (it will be greatly expanded very soon).